# How to offset thumbnails to the center?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I made few thumbs size. But some of them make total resize of original pict or make new with specified sizes from right bottom corner. Is this posible to centrilize thumbs? I meen to make new thumb with specified size but with offset to center / centilize them?

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

 if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'last-posts-thumb', 0, 160);
    add_image_size( 'last-posts-thumb-4-3', 120, 160, true);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried and use successfully this [code](http://bradt.ca/blog/image-crop-position-in-wordpress/) which allow to define image size using specific cropping position for this image size : `bt_add_image_size( 'product-screenshot', 300, 300, array( 'left', 'top' ) );`

It allow centering option so it looks like matching your purpose. I've added the code in a separate php file that I included into functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Tim Thumb script. It might help you with this. http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/08/timthumb-part-4-moving-crop-location/